# Write functions for methods in Rstudio

Tags: r, function, package, extension-methods

I would like to ask for your help. In fact, I am currently trying to create a package to simulate rolling an object and create functions to do so. More precisely, I have created the roll function that takes in argument a device as well as the number of times to roll the device.

```
roll <- function(device=device(), times=1 ) {
  if (class(device) != "device") {
    stop("the object must be of class device")
  }
  check_times(x=times)
  rolls <-  sample(device$sides, size=times,
                   replace= TRUE, prob= device$prob)
  obj <- list(rolls= rolls, sides = device$sides,
              prob= device$prob, total= times)
  class(obj) <- "rolls"
  print.rolls(obj)
}
```

I would actually like to create an extraction function such that if I do

```
             object <- roll(die, times = 100)
             oject[10]
```

I get the 10th roll.

Moreover, I would like also a function that would allow me to replace a given roll. Say "<-" such that

```
        object <- roll(two_side_die, times = 100)
        object[10] <- "head"
```

replace the 10th roll by head.

And finally, an addition method to be able to get

```
        roll(die, times= 300)
```

by doing for example

```
          roll(die, times = 100) + 200
```

Thank you very much!!

Comment: Write functions `\`[.rolls\` <- function(obj, ind) {...}` and `\`[.rolls<-\` <- function(obj, ind, newval) {...}` (the use of embedded backticks is intentional). The `obj` in your function will be the `object` in your question, `ind` will be 10, and `newval` will be `"head"`. From there, you should be able to do as you expect. Just make sure that these functions return the new object. For fun, you can also overload `print.rolls <- function(x, ...) {...}` if you want it do display in a particular fashion on the console.

Comment: Hello, thanks so much!

Would you have by any chance a link in which I can find more explanations about the `[.rolls` writing structure.

It actually worked fine with the first bracket function but not with the with the array one.

When I write, 

                    ``[.rolls<- <- function(x, ind, z) {
                     x$rolls[ind] <- 'z'
                      }``
it does not take in account the change.

(I used the embedded backticks)

Comment: From my previous comment: *"Just make sure that these functions return the new object"*. You are not. The problem is apparent if you look at what is actually returned when you do `x$rolls[ind] <- 'z'`. The return value from that assignment operation is just the value that was assigned, i.e., `'z'`. If you instead do `{ x$rolls[ind] <- 'z'; x;}`, you should get what you want.

Comment: See my answer ... I had the parts of the function name reversed, sorry.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you are already using some S3 method dispatch with `class(obj) <- "class"`, you should be able to do:

```
`[.rolls` <- function(obj, ind) obj$rolls[ind]
`[<-.rolls` <- function(obj, ind, value) { obj[["rolls"]][ind] <- value; obj; }
```

Some fake data:

```
foo <- list(rolls=10L+1:5, sides=6, probs = 1/6)
class(foo) <- "rolls"
foo[3]
# [1] 13
foo[3] <- 99L
foo
# $rolls
# [1] 11 12 99 14 15
# $sides
# [1] 6
# $probs
# [1] 0.1666667
# attr(,"class")
# [1] "rolls"
```

You can go so far as to pretty-print the object, though it only has interactive uses:

```
print.rolls <- function(x, ...) {
  cat("<Rolls>\n")
  cat("  len: ", length(x[["rolls"]]), "\n")
  cat("  other properties: ", paste(sort(setdiff(names(x), "rolls")), collapse = ", "), "\n")
}
foo
# <Rolls>
#   len:  5 
#   other properties:  probs, sides
```